# Serializing a List obtained through a WebMethod in C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, serialization

Hi I have the following code that is a webservice that takes two values sent by the client and uses them to query a database and then returns the result.

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapDocumentMethod]

public List<venda>  getListaVendas (string dt_min, string dt_max)
{
    List<venda> objVendaList = new List<venda>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=user;password=password."))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo where contact_moment >='" + dt_min + "' AND contact_moment <DATEADD(dd, 1, '" + dt_max + "')", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var objVenda = new venda();

                objVenda.id = dr["id"].ToString();
                objVenda.contact_moment = dr["contact_moment"].ToString();
                objVenda.nome = dr["nome"].ToString();
                objVenda.pacote = dr["pacote"].ToString();
                objVenda.telefone = dr["telefone"].ToString();
                objVenda.codigo_wc = dr["codigo_wc"].ToString();

                objVendaList.Add(objVenda);

            }
            dr.Close();
        }
    }
    return objVendaList ;
 }
```

The output it produces is something like this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with   it. The document tree is shown below.
<ArrayOfVenda xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<venda>
<id>9702775</id>
<contact_moment>2016-04-07 16:08:48</contact_moment>
<nome>name1</nome>
<pacote>teste1(001)</pacote>
<telefone>telephone</telefone>
<codigo_wc>Ucode</codigo_wc>
</venda>
</ArrayOfVenda>
```

So it seems that it doesn't have a XML structure associated with it. I've been searching and i think i am suposed to serialize the List i am returning but after searching i am still clueless how to go about this. Anyone has some guidelines about how i should do this? The desired output should be something like the one i have but with a header like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You should [parameterize your Sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx), see that link for an example. So really you just want an xml header in your response. How did you come to the conclusion that there is no XML header (how did you test this)?

Comment: The thing that is bothering me is the message: "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with   it. The document tree is shown below." But yes the only thing that is missing from the current output is that header. 
It's a asmx that i have running in IIS i simply input the  two values (dtmin and dtmax) and it returns me that output

Comment: `The thing that is bothering me is the message` -> Sure until your site gets hacked with a Sql Injection attack at which point that will be the thing bothering you but that might be much worse than this problem could ever be.

Comment: The site is not available to the outside so i guess that won't be a problem? 
But i aprecciate the input i will certainly improve that aspect of the code just wanted to get the desired output first.

Comment: Still a problem depending on who knows about the service especially for a larger organization. Also sql Server can cache the query plan 1x if you use parameters but without parameters every new call is a new query plan which can be very taxing.

Comment: I see i will change that using the link you provided thank you!